# Is there a way to check LEAD() function's value for NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to check for NULL the value returned by `LEAD()` function.

`SELECT LEAD(created_at) OVER (order by id, created_at) - created as diff`

Comment: please refer this http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-isnull/

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the `NULL` value is for the last row in the group.  In this case, you can just use the 3-argument form of `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT (LEAD(created_at, 1, <replacement value>) OVER (order by id, created_at) - 
        created_at
       ) as diff
```

Note that this only replaces `NULL` values that are the last values in the group.  If there are `NULL` values in the data, you will actually get `NULL`.  This is normally the behavior that you want.

Answer (score -1):

Suitable solution:

`SELECT coalesce(LEAD(created_at) OVER (order by id, created_at), now()) - created as diff`

Thank's

Comment: Or just use `lead(created_at, 1, now() OVER (ORDER BY id, created_at)`.